# HTML, JS: how can i display html text formatted, in a div with contenteditable, to view its output in a preview?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a minimal queue editor. I have two panels: one where i write the text/code and it colors in relation to the word, and then i have another panel with the preview function (views the output of the html code). Then the `code panel` and the `preview panel`.

[image]

Previously to build the `code panel`, i used a `<textarea>`. Using textarea, the text was NOT colored, but the `preview panel` worked correctly. Now i'm using a `div` and [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable). With them, the text is colored correctly, but the `preview panel` doesn't work and `undefined` is printed inside.

**PROBLEM:** The problem will probably be that the `preview panel` is unable to recover the html code from the code panel (div with [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable)), because the html text is not printed formatted (unlike the textarea which printed the formatted text). So, mistakenly, the output is printed in the code panel and not the html code

[image]

How can i display formatted text in the panel code and consequently display the output in the panel code?

**WHAT WOULD I WANT?** As you can see, if i write `<h1>This is a Heading</h1>` and `<p>This is a paragraph</p>` in the `code panel`, the formatted text is not printed, but the output is printed directly. I don't want this.

Instead, i would like to get this:

[image]

**index.html**

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true" oninput="showPreview()">

<!-- HTML CODE TO PRINT -->
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<!-- -->

</div>

<h3>PREVIEW</h3>
<div class="preview-area">
  <iframe id="preview-window"></iframe>
</div>
```

**style.css**

```
#editor {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #444;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: monospace;
}
.statement {
  color: orange;
}
```

**javascript.js**

```
//PREVIEW
function showPreview() {

    var editor = document.getElementById("editor").value;
    
    // var cssCode =
    //  "<style>" + document.getElementById("cssCode").value + "</style>";
    // var jsCode =
    //  "<scri" + "pt>" + document.getElementById("jsCode").value + "</scri" + "pt>";
    
    var frame = document.getElementById("preview-window").contentWindow.document;
    frame.open();
    //frame.write(htmlCode + cssCode + jsCode);
    frame.write(editor);
    frame.close();
}



// CHANGE COLOR TEXT
    var keywords = ["DIV", "DIV", "H1", "H1", "P", "P", "HELLO", "<", ">", "/"];
    // Keyup event
    document.querySelector('#editor').addEventListener('keyup', e => {
    // Space key pressed
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        var newHTML = "";
        // Loop through words
        str = e.target.innerText;
        chunks = str
          .split(new RegExp(
            keywords
              .map(w => `(${w})`)
              .join('|'), 'i'))
          .filter(Boolean),
        markup = chunks.reduce((acc, chunk) => {
          acc += keywords.includes(chunk.toUpperCase()) ?
          `<span class="statement">${chunk}</span>` :
          `<span class='other'>${chunk}</span>`
          return acc
        }, '')      
        e.target.innerHTML = markup;

        // Set cursor postion to end of text
        //    document.querySelector('#editor').focus()
        var child = e.target.children;
        var range = document.createRange();
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        range.setStart(child[child.length - 1], 1);
        range.collapse(true);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
        this.focus();
            
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&lt;` to "escape" the less-than characters in the `contenteditable`. This will make the code appear in the editor:

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true" oninput="showPreview()">

<!-- HTML CODE TO PRINT -->
&lt;h1>This is a Heading</h1>
&lt;p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<!-- -->

</div>
```

Then to have the line breaks reflected in the editor, apply `white-space: pre` to the `contenteditable`. We'd also need to reformat the text inside the `contenteditable` to ensure it shows as desired.

```css
#editor {
  /* … */
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true" oninput="showPreview()">&lt;h1>This is a Heading&lt;/h1>
&lt;p>This is a paragraph.&lt;/p></div>
```

The `<iframe>` result will not show in the snippet below due to browser security but the editor behavior can be previewed:

```js
//PREVIEW
function showPreview() {
  var editor = document.getElementById("editor").innerText;

  // var cssCode =
  //  "<style>" + document.getElementById("cssCode").value + "</style>";
  // var jsCode =
  //  "<scri" + "pt>" + document.getElementById("jsCode").value + "</scri" + "pt>";
  
  var frame = document.getElementById("preview-window").contentWindow.document;
  document.getElementById("preview-window").srcdoc = editor;
  frame.open();
  //frame.write(htmlCode + cssCode + jsCode);
  frame.write(editor);
  frame.close();
}

// CHANGE COLOR TEXT
var keywords = ["DIV", "DIV", "H1", "H1", "P", "P", "HELLO", "<", ">", "/"];
// Keyup event
document.querySelector("#editor").addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  // Space key pressed
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    var newHTML = "";
    // Loop through words
    str = e.target.innerText;
    (chunks = str
      .split(new RegExp(keywords.map((w) => `(${w})`).join("|"), "i"))
      .filter(Boolean)),
      (markup = chunks.reduce((acc, chunk) => {
        acc += keywords.includes(chunk.toUpperCase())
          ? `<span class="statement">${chunk}</span>`
          : `<span class='other'>${chunk}</span>`;
        return acc;
      }, ""));
    e.target.innerHTML = markup;

    // Set cursor postion to end of text
    //    document.querySelector('#editor').focus()
    var child = e.target.children;
    var range = document.createRange();
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    range.setStart(child[child.length - 1], 1);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    this.focus();
  }
});
```

```css
#editor {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #444;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre;
}
.statement {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true" oninput="showPreview()">&lt;h1>This is a Heading&lt;/h1>
&lt;p>This is a paragraph.&lt;/p></div>

<h3>PREVIEW</h3>
<div class="preview-area">
  <iframe id="preview-window"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: OK, thanks a lot :) A little curiosity: as soon as I open the html file, there is nothing in the preview. The preview is displayed only if I press any key in the panel code. How can I display the preview directly as soon as I open the html file? (I allow myself to ask only because I know it is a very very simple modification). P.S: I voted on your question and will accept the answer shortly. Thank you

Comment: You can display the preview directly as soon as one opens the html file by calling `showPreview()` directly, such as in the JavaScript.

Comment: How can I call him directly? In your code (and mine too) it says <div id="editor" contenteditable="true" oninput="showPreview()">. Isn't it already called that directly? What change should I make to call him directly?

Comment: You could add a call at the end of your JavaScript code, literally `showPreview();` on a new line.

Comment: Ah ok, so you meant to call the function directly in the script. I didn't understand (I'm new). A thousand thanks. I accepted your answer. You were kind and I really appreciated your help. Thank you